# sitemesh layout

Tags: java, layout, grails, stripes, sitemesh

The Stripes web framework includes a layout engine which provides the following feature:

### Layout Definition File - layout.jsp

```
<s:layout-definition>
  Header
  <div><s:layout-component name="body"/></div>
  Footer
</s:layout-definition>
```

### Page Using layout.jsp

```
<s:layout-render name="/layout.jsp">
  <s:layout-component name="body">
    Hello, reusable layout
  </s:layout-component>
</s:layout-render>
```

### Generated Content

```
Header
<div>Hello, reusable layout</div>
Footer
```

In the layout definition I specify the position of a component and the page defines the content of this component. I'm looking for an equivalent feature in Sitemesh, which I'm using in a Grails application.

It seems that Sitemesh will only only allow one to posititon (or decorate) the entire page body. Is there any way I can position more fine-grained content elements as above?

Answer (score 1):

If you need more fine-grained content elements, take a look at [Sitemesh Content Blocks](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.5%20Sitemesh%20Content%20Blocks)